# How can I have a datatype of array in mysql Sequelize instance?

Tags: mysql, arrays, sequelize.js

I am building an application that uses Node/Express and MySQL with Sequelize as the ORM. I want to have a datatype of Array, but the sequelize docs says this is limited to postgres only.

Basically, if I have a users table that has 3 columns for example (name, phone, favColors), I want favColors to get populated with an array of string values retrieved from the user. How can I do this?

Comment: you'll have to serialize your array and store as a string.

Comment: Thanks @Adam, I was going to just store the data as a STRING, and then split the values later, but I thought there may be a less hacky way.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use getter/setter functions for this:

```
favColors: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    get() {
        return this.getDataValue('favColors').split(';')
    },
    set(val) {
       this.setDataValue('favColors',val.join(';'));
    },
}
```

more info: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getters-setters-virtuals.html

Answer (score 14):

You can define your field as `json`:

```
type: Sequelize.JSON
```

And then save the data as an `array`

Comment: I wanted to implement this idea, but the vsCode's  intellisense adviced that it was only for postgreSQL. So I didn´t even tried

Comment: Yep, there are some kinds of data types that work only with some kinds of databases. You can read this [doc](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/other-data-types.html) to see if you can use or not a specific datatype.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```js
tags: {
    type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.TEXT),
    defaultValue: [],
}
```

Comment: This worked with a MYSQL database?

Answer (score 0):

```js
favColors: {
    type: Sequelize.JSON
}
```

if you're using typescript you could set the type as

```js
favColors: string[]
```