# I want to store array of object in MySQL in individual column with Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, sequelize.js

Previously I was finding how can I insert object array in my MySQL with Sequelize then I landed to one solution inserting array directly eg. [1,2] in a single column

```sql
insert into TABLE_NAME(id, marks) VALUES (21, [1, 2])
```

but I am looking for a solution which can be used in Sequelize to insert

```
{
  "id": 21 ,
  "marks": [90, 90] 
}
```

Eg query:

```sql
insert into TABLE_NAME(id, marks) VALUES ((21, 90),(21, 90))
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently still in **sequelize v5** , array datatype is only supported in `PostgreSQL`, there is no default way for `MySQL`. **[DOC](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/data-types.html)**

```
Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.TEXT)       // Defines an array. PostgreSQL only.
Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.ENUM)       // Defines an array of ENUM. PostgreSQL only.
```

But still there is **workaround** : **[CHECK THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41869335/2349407)**

Comment: type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.JSON) works on "sequelize": "^6.19.0"

Answer (score 0):

You can use type: Sequelize.JSON to store an object, but the order of fields is not preserved by MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You can stringify the array in the sequelize setter function of your model and set the datatype to string like in this example below

```
avatar: {
    type: dataType.STRING,
    set(val) {
      this.setDataValue("avatar", JSON.stringify(val ?? ""));
    },
  },
```

the 'avatar' is the column name of your table. You can now use `JSON.parse(avatar)` to convert it back to your array of objects when you fetches back from your database.